# Express route: some routes are not recognised

Tags: node.js, express, routes, get

Hello folks I need some help to overcome my multiple get route issue as I am new to the nodeJS technology. I have a controller file in which i have the list of the routes and the service function to be called on hitting them. My top 3-4 routes in the list works fine but routes after that does not work and gives me cast error. If I move them to the top of the router.get queue then they work fine. This is my folder structure currently.

```
 - Controller
   
     bookingController.js
 -  Model
   
     bookingModel.js
 -  Servcies
   
     bookingService.js
 - Server.js
```

And this is my controller file where i have configured the routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bookingService = require('../services/booking.service');

router.post('/register', newBooking);  router.get('/', getAll); 
router.get('/:villaName', getByVilla); 
router.get('/:checkInDate',getByDate);
router.get('/:checkInDate/:checkOutDate', getByDate);
router.get('/getGMV', getGMV);
```

So here the routes

```
router.get('/:checkInDate', getByDate);
router.get('/getGMV', getGMV);
```

does not work and if i move them above this route 'router.get('/', getAll); ' then it works perfectly And this is my server.js.

```
// api routes
app.use('/users', require('./controllers/users.controller'));
app.use('/booking', require('./controllers/booking.controller'));
app.use('/partner', require('./controllers/partner.controller'));
app.use('/agent', require('./controllers/agent.controller'));
app.use('/villas', require('./controllers/villas.controller'));
```

Can Someone please help me with this as I am new to nodeJS. This is the error I am facing for the last routes **{message: "Cast to date failed for value "getGMV" at path "checkInDate" for model "Booking""}**

***Apologies, stack overflow did not allow me to embed pictures in my post and thus sharing the link of the images in the post.***

Comment: Please do not post images of code.  Post  the relevant code IN YOUR QUESTION as text.  There are several dozen reasons why that is required here and many of those reasons help you get answers more accurately and quicker.  To start with, if we want to post a fixed version of your code as an answer, we now have to retype all your code rather than just copy and edit.  So, please use the "edit" link below your question and fix your question by pasting the relevant code into the question and format it appropriately as code.  Let me repeat - no code in images.

Comment: This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068923/some-express-router-routes-do-not-execute-middleware-function/68068993#68068993) is possibly relevant since you are showing a top level wild card route `router.get('/:checkInDate', getByDate)` which is often a problem, but we can't see enough of your code to actually know what's going on or even what the actual problem is.

Comment: I have updated my questions to be more accurate. please let me know if any other part of code or information is required.

Comment: As my comment indicated, your `router.get('/getGMV', getGMV);` will never get called because `router.get('/:checkInDate', getByDate);` matches EVERY top level URL so routing never gets to `router.get('/getGMV', getGMV);`.  Top level wildcard routes are evil and cause lots of problems.  Don't use them.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068923/some-express-router-routes-do-not-execute-middleware-function/68068993#68068993 for details.

Comment: Yes right, after removing the wild card routes my problem was solved. Thanks @jfriend00